# XSD 'inclusive or'

Tags: xml, xsd

I need an advice for a xml validation issue. My problem is that I need to set up an XSD for XML validation that defines two mandatory fields and two optional fields. According to available data the characterisics of the fields switch.

The XML shall be valid in case either one of the described cases are fulfilled.

1. It shall be possible to fill the fields AAA and BBB. When these fields are filled, CCC and DDD may be emtpy.
2. When the fields CCC and DDD are filled, the fields AAA and BBB shall be optional.

I was thinking about a structure like the following one but I am not able to save it with my ALTOVA XMLSPY 2012. It says the content model is not unique.

```
<xs:complexType name="ZZZType">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>Selection</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="XXX" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="AAA" type="AAAType" nillable="false"/>
        <xs:element name="BBB" type="BBBType" nillable="false"/>
        <xs:element name="CCC" type="CCCType" nillable="false" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="DDD" type="DDDType" nillable="false" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="AAA" type="AAAType" nillable="false" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="BBB" type="BBBType" nillable="false" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="CCC" type="CCCType" nillable="false"/>
        <xs:element name="DDD" type="DDDType" nillable="false"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Is there a way to realize what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Not with XML Schema</strike>. **Correction**: not with XML Schema 1.0 (thanks to @PetruGardea for the observation). With XSD 1.0 you can restrict the structure of complex types and the contents of simple types, but it's not possible to restrict types based on the content of other types.

To do that with XSD 1.0 you need another layer of validation which you can achieve using a programming language, or you can use something like [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/), which is a very popular solution. You can download the ISO standard and find a lot of examples and tutorials from the official site. If you know XPath and XSLT you will probably find it quite easy to use.

With XML Schema 1.1 there is support for assertions, which are written in XPath 2.0 (which includes if/else, loops, and all that you already have with XPath 1.0). You can probably add to your `<complexType>` something like this:

```
<xs:assert test="(AAA and BBB or CCC or DDD) or (CCC and DDD or AAA or BBB)" />
```

(I didn't test that - I'll update this post as soon as I do, or someone might post a better answer in the meantime).

Comment: You should be more specific... It is possible with XSD 1.1. The typical answer it XSD 1.0 + Schematron, or XSD 1.1

Comment: Thanks for the correction @PetruGardea. I'm going to fix the answer. I wasn't aware that asserts were supported in XSD 1.1. That's cool.

Comment: Yes some features in XSD 1.1 are very cool. Unfortunately support for XSD 1.1 is not very wide spread so often can't be used for this reason.